# Help setting up integral: $\iint_{\mathbb R^2} \frac{1}{(1+4x^2+9y^2)^2} dx dy$

Tags: calculus, vector-analysis

> Evaluate $\iint_{\mathbb R^2} \frac{1}{(1+4x^2+9y^2)^2} dx dy$

If I use polar coordinates I get
$$\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^\infty \frac{r}{(1+4r^2\cos^2\theta+9r^2\sin^2\theta)^2} drd\theta.$$

However, I am not sure where to go from here.

Comment: Try converting the cos^2(theta) to tan^2(theta/2) half angle formula.

Comment: @RishabhDeepSingh I had to make an edit. Should I still use your hint?

Comment: Yes it will still work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We substitute first $2x=s$, $3y=t$, so $6dx\wedge dy = ds\wedge dt$. The integral is after this easily computed.
$$
\begin{aligned}
\iint_{\mathbb R^2} \frac{1}{(1+4x^2+9y^2)^2} \; dx\; dy
&=
\frac 16\iint_{\mathbb R^2} \frac{1}{(1+s^2+t^2)^2} \;ds\; dt
\\
&=
\frac 16\int_0^\infty\int_0^{2\pi} \frac{1}{(1+r^2)^2} \; r\;dr\; d\theta
\\
&=
\frac 16\cdot2\pi\cdot \frac 12 
\int_0^\infty \frac{1}{(1+r^2)^2} \;d(r^2)
\\
&=
\frac 16\cdot2\pi\cdot \frac 12 
\left[\ -\frac{1}{1+r^2}\ \right]_0^\infty
\\
&=\frac \pi6\ .
\end{aligned}
$$

Comment: Wolfranapha is showing Pi/6 http://www.wolframalpha.com/widgets/view.jsp?id=f5f3cbf14f4f5d6d2085bf2d0fb76e8a

Comment: Should $x=s/2$ and $y=3/t$?

Comment: Thanks! I put the $6$ on the false side, of course it is $2x=s$, not $x=2s$, and so on... I will edit it...

Comment: because the substitution actually is $x=s/2,\quad y=t/3$, so the six goes to the denominator. Apart from that it is a nice solution (+1)